Ignore only a specific patch version range with dependabot ignore commands
I have a repo with grouped dependabot updates enabled. A certain dependency, let's call it foo, has a bug in versions 0.7.6 to 0.7.8 but all the other grouped updates are fine, so I'd like to tell dependabot to exclude foo versions 0.7.6-0.7.8. foo is currently on version 0.7.5.
I've tried the following dependabot commands but none seem to do it:

@dependabot ignore foo patch version only ignores 0.7.8, so reopens with 0.7.7. This works but is tedious as one has to run the command as many times as there are patch versions to ignore.
@dependabot ignore foo ~0.7.8 doesn't work. Dependabot doesn't reply
@dependabot ignore foo <=0.7.8 doesn't work either
@dependabot ignore foo [>= 0.7.6, < 0.7.9] also doesn't work

